# Trying to delete bad face, can select edges but not face

Tags: modeling, geometry, extrude, knife-tool, svg

I am using knife project onto an object to make recessed portions. On the edge of object, I would like to inset and do a negative extrude, however, I end up with a thin face I cannot get rid of with delete or dissolve. I am able to select the edges but when I switch to face mode, nothing is there even if visually there is something there. Thank you so much[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/WaKXGeyA thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing select all and merge by distance because you have overlapping vertices. I don't see the part that you show but for example for this part I would select these faces and delete them:

[image]

Then same thing for these faces:

[image]

And select this whole edge loops and fill:

[image]